# Azure Function : Add environment specific config variable file in VS 2017 Preview 4

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

When new azure function project is created. 'local.setting.json' the file gets created as part of the project, how to add environment specific configuration file like we do for ASP MVC Core. Myself tried adding, 'local.settings.development.json' that did not work. Also tried 'development.settings.json' that too did not work either.

What is the correct way of creating the environment specific config file using visual studio 2017 Preview 3 for azure functions project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local.setting.json` is the file which is used for local development only. This file is not deployed to Azure: the settings are taken from `Environment` while running in the cloud.

So, if you have beta/production Function App, you will configure their settings in App Service Settings.